# Character Limit For IBM Watson Using Curl

Tags: curl, websphere, text-to-speech, ibm-watson

My Curl code will not accept any text over a certain amount.
No errors it just wont do the TTS.

Are there limits?

Example Code:

```js
curl -X POST -u "apikey:MYKEY" ^
--header "Content-Type: application/json" ^
--header "Accept: audio/wav" ^
--data "{\"text\":\"TEXT.\"}" ^
--output MYTEXT.wav ^
"https://api.us-south.text-to-speech.watson.cloud.ibm.com/instances/d73ba88c-84fc-45d2-b1bd-7b95066c280a/v1/synthesize?voice=en-US_MichaelV3Voice"
```

Comment: What Operating System, shell and curl version are you using?

Comment: Windows 10 Curl V3 I think.

Comment: cmd line on windows supports around 2000 characters. The command runs for me on Windows 10 using curl 7.74.0 from https://curl.se/windows/. Note I did not bother to sign up for a key so get an error in the downloaded file which I kind of expected.